# Execute sequential program on all cores within Windows-based Multi-Node Cluster?

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, windows-server-2012-r2, hpc, windows-server

How to do I execute sequential program (same executable) on all cores within Windows-based Multi-Node cluster (Windows 2012 R2 servers)?

My current program is just using C# `System.Diagnostics.Process` to execute a program on each available core in computer (e.g., 4 runs for 4 cores). However, I want to do that on all available cores in network connected cluster (e.g., 8 runs for 2*4 cores in the 2-node cluster)?

How do I do it? And related to it, how do I set up compute cluster with Windows servers? Do I use HPC Pack 2012 provided by Microsoft? Or HPC Pack 2012 and MPI?

Comment: What do you mean with "sequential program"?  Do you mean to run the same non-parallelized code on all cpu cores (potentially using different data?)

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Same non-parallelized code/executable and different data. The main issue is how do I do it on Windows? Do I set up cluster with HPC Pack first?